# Alternate Row Colors in Html Tables Using Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

How does one alternate row colors in a table in django that's generated using a for loop from a list? In asp.net it is possible to do math on the view to easily calculate that, but from what I understand that kind of math is not possible in django, so I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle).

```
{% for o in some_list %}
  <tr class="{% cycle 'red' 'green' %}">
    ...
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```